# jQuery Mobile, show/hide checkbox/radio and update displayed inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove inputs from a checkbox group. The example below works, but when the input is removed I don't get rounded edges anymore on the last input item. It just cuts off. I thought running a checkboxradio('refresh') would rectify the issues, but it hasn't. Any ideas?

```
if(some condition) {
  $('.hideThis').hide();
  $('[name=values]').checkboxradio('refresh');
} else {
    $('.hideThis').show();
    $('[name=values]').checkboxradio('refresh');
}

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <input type="checkbox" name="values" id="val1" value="val1">
        <label for="val1">Value 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="values" id="val2" value="val2">
        <label for="val2">Value 2</label>
        <div class="hideThis">
            <input type="checkbox" name="values" id="val3" value="val3">
            <label for="val3">Value 3</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Based on the OP comment, the answer below works for *Jquery Mobile V1.3.0*.

For *Jquery Mobile V1.2.0*, instead of `ui-last-child` class, use `ui-corner-bottom` and `ui-controlgroup-last` classes for the last checkbox.

**Original answer** "*Jquery Mobile V1.3.0*"

Last checkbox has `ui-last-child` styling. So when you hide/remove the last *checkbox*, JQM doesn't add that class to the previous checkbox. Therefore, you have to work your way through, by adding `ui-last-child` style to the previous *checkbox* of the hidden one.

If you hide the first *checkbox*, use `ui-first-child` instead.

**Markup**

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="hidethis">hide this</a>

<form>
 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Vertical:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-v-2a">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2a">One</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2b" id="checkbox-v-2b">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2c" id="checkbox-v-2c">
    <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JQM**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#hidethis', function () {
 $('div.ui-checkbox:last-child').prev('div').find('label').addClass('ui-last-child');
 $('div.ui-checkbox:last-child').hide();
});
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/StRQ4/1/)**

Comment: This worked, but in JQM 1.2 I had to use addClass('ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last')

Comment: Great :) ill mention this in my answer.